# How to increment x by y in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, increment

I have a variable `weight` and a state value `deliveryFee`.

As the value of `weight` increases I need to increment the value of `deliveryFee` according to this pattern:

```
Up to 2 kg => $3.40
Up to 5 kg => $3.80
Up to 10 kg => $4.20
```

And then for every additional 10kg I need to increment `deliveryfee` by a further $3.50

I can do the first part easily using a ternary operator:

```
weight <= 2
  ? setDeliveryFee(3.4)
  : weight <= 5
  ? setDeliveryFee(3.8)
  : weight <= 10
  && setDeliveryFee(4.2)
```

But I can't work out how to increment the `deliveryFee` by 3.5 every time `weight` increases by an additional 10.

I know I could simply continue this pattern to achieve the result:

```
weight + 1 <= 2
  ? setDeliveryFee(3.4)
  : weight + 1 <= 5
  ? setDeliveryFee(3.8)
  : weight + 1 <= 10
  ? setDeliveryFee(4.2)
  : weight + 1 <= 20
  ? setDeliveryFee(7.7)
  : weight + 1 <= 30
  ? setDeliveryFee(11.2)
  : weight + 1 <= 40
  ? setDeliveryFee(14.7)
  && weight + 1 <= 50 && setDeliveryFee(18.2);
```

But since `weight` could theoretically be any figure this is not fool proof so I really need a formula to accomplish this.

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Do yourself and anyone else who will use this code a favor and don't use a ternary for this.. It's so much harder to read/understand, and is much more error prone than using `if-else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this equation `4.2 + (Math.ceil((weight / 10) - 1) * 3.5)`, also I prefer to use `if/else` or switch conditions rather than ternary operator in case there are a lot of cases for better readability.

```js
const transform = (weight) => {
  if (weight <= 2) {
    return 3.4
  } else if (weight <= 5) {
    return 3.8
  } else if (weight <= 10) {
    return 4.2
  } else {
    return 4.2 + (Math.ceil((weight / 10) - 1) * 3.5)
  }
}

console.log(transform(5))
console.log(transform(10))
console.log(transform(20))
console.log(transform(30))
console.log(transform(40))
console.log(transform(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store `deliveryFee` as React state; it is derived from `weight`, so if you just directly calculate it from `weight`, it will automatically update on every render to match the latest `weight`.

```
const calculateDeliveryFee = weight => {
  if(weight <= 2)
    return 3.4;

  if(weight <= 5)
    return 3.8;

  if(weight <= 10)
    return 4.2;

  // rest of your conditions 

  return 18.2;
}
```

The `calculateDeliveryFee` will return the value of the first `if` condition that is met, so you don't have to use `else if`/`else`. `return 18.2` will execute if none of the previous conditions are `true`. Then in your React component,

```
const deliveryFee = calculateDeliveryFee(weight);
```